# Default migrate table name rename

Tags: django, django-authentication

Since my project would like to create all the table into an old database,

It would be a problem if I use the default name from Django.

Is there any way to rename all the table like the JPG below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you don't mind refer on this [extending session and use it in django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/sessions/#example) make abstract session class

if you want extends and change the default class name to use  instead of Session class to AbstractBaseSession

Comment: not really work~
Although it created a table with the exact name but the column is not the same with the one I want

from django.db import models
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

class TempUser(Session):
    class Meta:
        db_table = "temp_user"

It comes out two table after make migrate

Comment: Thx for your help...it works ~ but that is not the one I want anyway I found out that solution. That is directly edit all the models in Lib and makemigrations again then migrate~